# mxGraph: Which event is fired when I move a handle point of an edge?

Tags: javascript, graph, mxgraph

I move the point and I want to save the position after the movement. How can I catch this event? I know, the edge gets the points after moving, I can find control points in the geometry. But I need the moment of the end of movement.

[image: edge point moving]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps, but I usually have a listener to mxEvent.CHANGE, and process each change...

Something like this:

```
model.addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function(sender, evt)
{
   var changes = evt.getProperty('edit').changes;
   for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {   
     if (changes[i].constructor.name ==  "mxTerminalChange") {
       // DO SOMETHING
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One of my failures is, maybe: I have to write `model.addListener` instead of `graph.addListener`. The other is, I have to add this listener before the model update, because when I add it after, there's nothing in the console. Although `mxTerminalChange` is not what happens on the point move, but I think, now I can find what I need. So thank you!

Comment: The edge is in the `changes`, and I can find the new values of the points in the geometry! Works fine, thank you! :) ImI

Comment: I'm glad this was useful!!