# mxgraph - edit existing edges

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

i am trying to realize: that i can edit (reconnect to another vertex) an existing edge without selecting it before.

I dont find any solutions for that. My idea, i have to find a way to recognize clicks on start or end of a edge and then delete the old connection manually and start a new connection manually.

But i dont find a way to recognize such click event.

Can u help me?
Maybe u can tell me how to recognize such event or you can tell that this function is allready implemented and i just have to activate it with the setting xxxx ;)

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469751/mxgraph-which-event-is-fired-when-i-move-a-handle-point-of-an-edge/62528944#62528944, let me know if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answere but i am looking for a way to reconnect an edge to another vertex without select it before

Comment: How do you want to edit it? Programmatically? Or with specific actions in the interface?

Comment: So i wish: if i click ( & hold) on start or end of edge - it should disconnect from current port and start a reconnecting like with the: connectionHandler.start(...)

Comment: Short: I looking for a method or something like that: connectionHandler.edit(edge, terminalToRemove, x, y);